# multiple levels of inheritance and dynamic_cast

Tags: c++

Some background first:

I am working on some legacy code that implements UI interfaces. The code is structured in a way that it has a base class (actually it's a struct) WinBase which is then derived to all sorts of graphical objects.

```
WinBase:
 - Button
 - DialogWin
 - (etc...)
 - EditWin
```

WinBase has a member `WinBase **children` that is used to keep tabs on all of the children of each object. These children are created and destroyed during runtime in the standard new[]/delete[] fashion.

All methods/functions of these objects assume that they are receiving a pointer to a `WinBase` object, and `dynamic_cast<>` is used to ensure/validate that the appropriate pointers are being used.

A later change to the code added two more classes/structs (`ListBox` and `TextBox`), that are derived from `EditWin` which in turn is derived from `WinBase`.

So... I have pointers to `WinBase` that being casted to `ListBox` and `TextBox`. As I said, `dynamic_cast<>` is used throughout the code, but I am not sure how safe this is when a function like this constructor is called.

```
TextBox(WinBase *pw,(...));
```

How safe is it to cast directly from `WinBase` to `ListBox` and vice versa (for instance)?

Comment: Safe in what way? `dynamic_cast<>` will evaluate to a NULL pointer if the run-time type doesn't permit the cast. As long as you're checking that the result is non-null, you're safe. If this is not the question, you really need to provide more detail, and the code you specifically are confused about (and in what way).

Comment: Rather than returning 0, it will throw a `std::bad_cast` exception if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @jogojapan Always return 0 if works with pointers.

Comment: It's save if both classes are polymorphic

Comment: @ForEveR Ah right. I should have checked.

Comment: This sounds more like Multi-level inheritance rather than Multiple inheritance. I'll update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why would you want to cast a `WinBase` to a `ListBox` when a `ListBox` is given to a method expecting a `WinBase`? If you need a cast there, you should re-think the design, as methods expecting the `WinBase` should operate only on `WinBase's` interface.

If, and only if, `ListBox` is derived from `WinBase` (either directly or indirectly), you can always cast from a `ListBox*` to a `WinBase*` (or reference), because a ListBox [**IS A**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `WinBase`.

Casting the other way around is NOT safe, because you will never know if the `WinBase*` you got is actually a `ListBox*` or something else and that calls for trouble. You can of course use `dynamic_cast<>` to test if it really is a `ListBox*`, but any dynamic cast calls for a review of your design.

Especially that kind of down-cast calls for trouble in a constructor, because when you are not getting what you wanted, what is your code supposed to do? Throwing exceptions, as the only way out is not such a good idea and at its best [avoided at all](http://herbsutter.com/2008/07/25/constructor-exceptions-in-c-c-and-java/) (unless you know what you are doing).

Comment: The code in question is legacy code so the author is probably unable to redesign it to avoid dynamic casts.  And `dynamic_cast` is not always a bad thing.  Like everything else it has its uses, i.e. the [acyclic visitor](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CE8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.objectmentor.com%2Fresources%2Farticles%2Facv.pdf&ei=VhIAUNDpMsLj0QG2z7H0Bw&usg=AFQjCNGMyoy2E1JAuc_3CHEZnsq_nS8H4Q).

Comment: Sure, thats true. However, the OP did not seem to be very familiar C++'s inheritance subtleties that are quite easy to trip about. My intention was to point out that both directions are ok, one is always safe, the other, well, is not :-)

Comment: Since I got to change this code I've been reading about the subtleties of inheritance ;) and my main concern here is if I can skip the intermediate object when upcasting to WinBase or if I have to do a sequence of casts to reach the base class.

Comment: @Andre then I'm sorry that I got your question wrong. You don't need a sequence of casts, since a ListBox is implicitly also a WinBase as EditWin is one.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can try to use boost::polymorphic_cast or boost::polymorphic_downcast http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/conversion/cast.htm it`s throw exception if dynamic_cast returns 0.